# How to convert an Array method to an ArrayList method?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, type-conversion

How can I alter the below method to work with an ArrayList?
I was thinking something like this:

```
public static boolean sortArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    return false;
}
```

but i'm not sure how to complete it.

Here is the method that I am trying to convert from working with an Array to instead work with an ArrayList:

```
public static boolean sortArrayList(final int[] data) {
    for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i-1] > data[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since your sortArrayList method does not sort the ArrayList, you may want to rename it to something like isASortedArrayList

Comment: Your method name! It could literally not be any more misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean sortArrayList(final ArrayList <Integer> data) {
    for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if (data.get(i - 1) > data.get(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few problems with the accepted answer, as given by @Sanj: (A) it doesn't handle nulls within the list, (B) it is unnecessarily specialized to `ArrayList<Integer>` when it could easily be merely `Iterable<Integer>`, and (C) the method name is misleading.

NOTE: For (A), it's quite possible that getting an NPE is appropriate - the OP didn't say. For the demo code, I assume that nulls are ignorable. Other interpretations a also fair, e.g. null is always a "least" value (requiring different coding, *LAAEFTR*). Regardless, the behaviour should be JavaDoc'ed - which I didn't do in my demo  #8>P

NOTE: For (B), keeping the specialized version ***might*** improve runtime performance, since the method "knows" that the backing data is in an array and the compiler ***might*** extract some runtime efficiency over the version using an `Iterable` but such claim seem dubious to me and, in any event, I would want to see benchmark results to support such. ***ALSO*** Even the version I demo could be further abstracted using a generic element type (vs limited to `Integer`). Such a method might have definition like:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isAscendingOrder(final Iterable<T> sequence)
```

NOTE: For (C), I follow @Valentine's method naming advice (almost). I like the idea so much, I took it one step further to explicitly call out the directionality of the checked-for-sortedness.

Below is a demonstration class that shows good behaviour for a `isAscendingOrder` which address all those issues, followed by similar behaviour by @Sanj's solution (until the NPE). When I run it, I get console output:

```
true, true, true, true, false, true
------------------------------------
true, true, true, true, false, 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SortCheck.sortArrayList(SortCheck.java:35)
    at SortCheck.main(SortCheck.java:78)
```

.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SortCheck
{
    public static boolean isAscendingOrder(final Iterable<Integer> sequence)
    {
        Integer prev = null;
        for (final Integer scan : sequence)
        {
            if (prev == null)
            {
                prev = scan;
            }
            else
            {
                if (scan != null)
                {
                    if (prev.compareTo(scan) > 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    prev = scan;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean sortArrayList(final ArrayList<Integer> data)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            if (data.get(i - 1) > data.get(i))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> createArrayList(final Integer... vals)
    {
        final ArrayList<Integer> rval = new ArrayList<>();

        for(final Integer x : vals)
        {
            rval.add(x);
        }

        return rval;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final ArrayList<Integer> listEmpty     = createArrayList();
        final ArrayList<Integer> listSingleton = createArrayList(2);
        final ArrayList<Integer> listAscending = createArrayList(2, 5, 8, 10  );
        final ArrayList<Integer> listPlatuea   = createArrayList(2, 5, 5, 10  );
        final ArrayList<Integer> listMixedUp   = createArrayList(2, 5, 3, 10  );
        final ArrayList<Integer> listWithNull  = createArrayList(2, 5, 8, null);

        System.out.print(isAscendingOrder(listEmpty    ) + ", ");
        System.out.print(isAscendingOrder(listSingleton) + ", ");
        System.out.print(isAscendingOrder(listAscending) + ", ");
        System.out.print(isAscendingOrder(listPlatuea  ) + ", ");
        System.out.print(isAscendingOrder(listMixedUp  ) + ", ");
        System.out.print(isAscendingOrder(listWithNull ) + "\n");

        System.out.println("------------------------------------");

        System.out.print(sortArrayList(listEmpty    ) + ", ");
        System.out.print(sortArrayList(listSingleton) + ", ");
        System.out.print(sortArrayList(listAscending) + ", ");
        System.out.print(sortArrayList(listPlatuea  ) + ", ");
        System.out.print(sortArrayList(listMixedUp  ) + ", ");
        System.out.print(sortArrayList(listWithNull ) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below function, it takes `integer array` and converts it into a `ArrayList` and then computes the result :

```
public static boolean sortArrayList(final int[] data) {
        List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
            aList.add(data[index]);

        for (int i = 1; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            if (aList.get(i - 1) > aList.get(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```